# How do I go about accessing a view when the activity is created?

Tags: android

So I'm trying to use SharedPreferences and with that I need to get access to the `LinearLayout` that I'm going to put the data in.

I have always tried to access the `LinearLayout` via ID. I have tried accessing it from `onCreate`, a function called from `onCreate`, and now I'm trying to initialize the `LinearLayout` from the fragment that it is a part of in the `onCreateView` method.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentHome fragmentHome;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this is also used to add the fragment to a ViewPagerAdapter
        fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();

        // I've tried it here
        linearLayout = fragmentHome.getLayout();

        // I was also thinking about calling this only after the activity restarts but I don't know how. Any thoughts on this would be helpful too
        reload();
    }

    public void reload() {

        linearLayout = fragmentHome.getLayout();
    }
}
```

*FragmentHome.java*

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public FragmentHome() {} // required empty constructor

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        // I thought this would fix my problem
        linearLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        return v;
    }

    public LinearLayout getLayout() {
        return linearLayout;
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough code. You can always request more if you think more is needed.

Every time I run the program, `linearLayout` is initialized properly. The problem arises when I close the app and open it again. Then `linearLayout` is 'initialized' as null. I can clarify more but I don't know what else needs to be said except for what can be done about this problem?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue. And, again, if the `LinearLayout` is in the `Fragment`, you should be handling it in the `Fragment`, not the `Activity`. An `Activity` should never be directly accessing a `Fragment`'s `View`s.

Comment: @MikeM. you're right. I'm sorry. It's just that the work I'm doing has become a bit annoying and nobody has really provided me with an answer that has worked so far. So what you're saying is that if I have a bunch of functions that pertain to a fragment, I should be defining them in the fragment's class? And yes, the `LinearLayout` is part of the fragment and the functions all have to do with the `LinearLayout` and what goes in it.

Comment: Yep, exactly. You've found the `LinearLayout` in `FragmentHome` already, so now you just need to populate it. You can get the same `SharedPreferences` in the `Fragment` that you would in the `Activity`, so there's no hurdle there. If you want to populate the `LinearLayout` right there in `onCreateView()`, go ahead, though it might be a little cleaner, code-wise, to do it `onViewCreated()`. Ultimately, there's no difference, however.